# Spark - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.reflect.api.JavaUniverse.runtimeMirror

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea, apache-spark

I am using Scala 2.11.8 and used maven to build the jar file in IntelliJ

I ran my program in mobaxterm:

```
/opt/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/spark-submit --class CDR.SQL cdr-maven-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

This is the error message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.reflect.api.JavaUniverse.runtimeMirror(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Lscala/reflect/api/JavaUniverse$JavaMirror;
>           at CDR.SQL$.(SQL.scala:24)
>           at CDR.SQL$.(SQL.scala)
>           at CDR.SQL.main(SQL.scala)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

This is my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>cdr-maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>cdr-maven</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>apache-repo</id>
            <name>Apache Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/releases</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.15.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-hive_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

How do I resolve this?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: is your issue resolved? if yes how did u resoved? I am facing same issue

Answer (score 3):

Have you downloaded Spark distribution or build it by yourself?

Spark 1.6 was built by default with Scala 2.10. Please change your Scala version to 2.10 or update Spark to 2.0, which is built by default with Scala 2.11

Answer (score 0):

Change the `Scala` version to 2.12.12. This solved my problem. Also note that the `spark core` and `spark sql` versions should be the same.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.ravitutorial.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>SparkProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <scala.tools.version>2.12</scala.tools.version>
        **<scala.version>2.12.12</scala.version>**
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core was 2.3.1 update to 2.4.2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.tools.version}</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_${scala.tools.version}</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.databricks/spark-avro -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-avro_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.esotericsoftware.kryo/kryo -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.esotericsoftware.kryo</groupId>
            <artifactId>kryo</artifactId>
            <version>2.24.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.38</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>${scala.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.delta/delta-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.delta</groupId>
            <artifactId>delta-core_${scala.tools.version}</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Answer (score -1):

Check the version.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
```

Looks like you are using 2.15.x version.

Comment: It's Maven plugin version, not Scala version