# Dataframes scala.reflect.api.JavaUniverse.runtimeMirror(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;) error

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, pom.xml

when I run a normal wordcount program(with below code) with out any Dataframe included I am able run the application with spark-submit.

```
object wordCount {   
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {   
 val logFile= "path/thread.txt"    
 val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark Word Count")    
 val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)     
 val file = sc.textFile(logFile)    
 val counts = file.flatMap(_.split(" ")).map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)    

 counts.saveAsTextFile("path/output1234")
 sc.stop()    
  }    
}
```

But when I run the below code

```
    import scala.reflect.runtime.universe

    import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
    import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
    import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.rddToPairRDDFunctions
object wordCount {    
          def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {    
           val logFile = "path/thread.txt"    
         val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark Word Count")    
         val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)    
         val file = sc.textFile(logFile)    
         val counts = file.flatMap(_.split(" ")).map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)    
        case class count1(key:String,value:Int)    
         val sqlContext =  new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)    
        import sqlContext.implicits._;    
          counts.toDF.registerTempTable("count1")    
           val counts1 = sqlContext.sql("select * from count1")     
         counts.saveAsTextFile("path/output1234")    
         sc.stop()    
          }    
        }
```

I am getting the below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.reflect.api.JavaUniverse.runtimeMirror(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Lscala/reflect/api/JavaMirrors$JavaMirror;
 at com.cadillac.spark.sparkjob.wordCount$.main(wordCount.scala:18)
```

I am not sure what I am missing.

Pom.xml I am using is as below,

```
<name>sparkjob</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
  <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.10</version>
</dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Please suggest any changes.

My cluster is with

spark-version 2.1.0-mapr-1703
Scala version 2.11.8

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your cluster is spark-version 2.1.0-mapr-1703 Scala version 2.11.8 and your dependency is with spark version 1.6.1 and scala as 2.10 ?

Answer (score 0):

If you go to [this documentation](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/FAQ.md#what-does-this-mean-noclassdeffounderror-scalacollectiongentraversableonceclass) the reason for the error is defined there as

> > This means that there is a mix of Scala versions in the libraries used in your code. The collection API is different between Scala 2.10 and 2.11 and this the most common error which occurs if a Scala 2.10 library is attempted to be loaded in a Scala 2.11 runtime. To fix this make sure that the name has the correct Scala version suffix to match your Scala version.

So changing your *dependencies* from

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.1</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

to

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.0</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and add one more *dependency*

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-lang/scala-library -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.8</version>
</dependency>
```

I guess the error should go away

Comment: There must be a dozen of dupes for this :)

Comment: I searched for it but couldn't find one. :) So read a document that i linked in my answer and I posted . @eliasah, did you find any?

Comment: Not important. I'll close it when I find :)

Comment: @eliasah It's always hard to find dupe for such question, but yes, it's a common question about Spark :)

Comment: @eliasah For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39652155/spark-exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-scala-reflect-ap/39659367#39659367 But it was not accepted

Comment: @T.Gawęda I think that it is what happens with most. We answer them and then the OP removes them. They are usually ashamed to have encountered such an error and asked about it.